# перебор вложенных словарей неопределенной глубины

Tags: python, циклы, рекурсия, словари, перебор

На вход подается случайный словарь, в котором хранятся вложенные словари, неопределенной глубины(в каждом словаре может быть N вложенных друг в друга словарей? ) что то вроде:

```
{'all': {'animals':{'predators':{'more':{...}}}}, 
'people':['women', men], 
'others':{}}
```

Вопрос: для того, что бы вывести только списки(как некое логическое завершение вложенности словаря), которые находятся на заранее неизвестной глубине, потребуется использовать рекурсию? Или существует какой-то более практичный и безопасный способ?

Comment: рекурсия - практичный и безопасный способ для данной задачи

Comment: а если вложенность больше 1000? опять с setrecursionlimit играться? можно через списки попробовать (pop + attach) тогда можно обойтись обычным while

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать следующий подход:

1. у вас есть список со значениями словаря
2. вы просматриваете эти значения предварительно удалив их из списка
3. если значение является словарем - вы добавляете в список его элементы

По сути это замена рекурсии

```
arr = {'all': {'animals':{'predators':{'more':[1, 2, 3]}}},
'people':['women', 'men'],
'others':{}}


tmp = [arr]

while tmp:
    elem = tmp.pop()

    if type(elem) == dict:
        for obj in elem.values():
            if type(obj) == dict:
                tmp.append(obj)
            else:
                print(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {"all":{"animals":{"predators":{"more":1}}},"people":["women","men"],"others":{}}

def recursive_flatten_iterator(d):
  for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
      yield v
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      yield from recursive_flatten_iterator(v)
            

for x in recursive_flatten_iterator(x):
  print(x)
```